# How do I map a JSON map of list of map from API for HTTP get request

Tags: json, flutter, http, mapping, get-request

I keep getting this error:

> NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => Name1Name2))

I am trying very hard to solve this error. I am certain I am not mapping the data properly.

My fake REST API from which I'm fetching and sending the data to

```
"messagesBetweenTwoUsers": {
    "Name1Name2": [
      {
        "senderName": "John",
        "message": "How are you doing?"
      }
    ]
  }
```

This is my get messages file

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'messages_model.dart';

Future<List<MessageModel>> getMessages() async {
  try {
    var getResponse = await http.get(
      Uri.parse("http://127.0.0.1:3000/messagesBetweenTwoUsers"),
    );

    if (getResponse.statusCode == 200) {
     
      String getData = getResponse.body;

      var jsonData =
          jsonDecode(getData);

      var getResult = jsonData["Name1Name2"].map(
        (e) => Name1Name2.fromJson(e),
      );


//here it throws me an error, in getResult, right when I am using map()
//NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.
//Receiver: null
//Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => Name1Name2))


      return getResult; 
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  } catch (error) {
    debugPrint("ERROR IN FETCHING FROM GET-MESSAGE-API: $error");
  }
  return [];
}
```

My model class

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class MessageModel {
    MessageModel({
        required this.name1Name2,
    });

    final List<Name1Name2> name1Name2;

    factory MessageModel.fromRawJson(String str) => MessageModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory MessageModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MessageModel(
        name1Name2: List<Name1Name2>.from(json["name1name2"].map((x) => Name1Name2.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name1name2": List<dynamic>.from(name1Name2.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Name1Name2 {
    Name1Name2({
        required this.senderName,
        required this.message,
    });

    final String senderName;
    final String message;

    factory Name1Name2.fromRawJson(String str) => Name1Name2.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory Name1Name2.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Name1Name2(
        senderName: json["senderName"],
        message: json["message"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "senderName": senderName,
        "message": message,
    };
}
```

Comment: You have to make sure that JohnMark exists

Comment: @CodeMaster I am sending post request to add the new users. I think the mapping is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

This error says you are accessing a key which is not found directly into the JSON data. Looking into your JSON data, you have the key `Name1Name2` nested into the `messagesBetweenTwoUsers` key value. Therefore, in order to access the value of the `Name1Name2` key you should call first the `messagesBetweenTwoUsers` key, like this:

```js
var getResult = jsonData["messagesBetweenTwoUsers"]["Name1Name2"].map(
  (e) => Name1Name2.fromJson(e),
);
```

EDITED:
Use this JSON model instead:

```js
{
  "participants": [
    {
      "senderName": "John",
      "receiverName": "Jakiro",
      "message": "How are you doing?"
    }
  ]
}
```

And decode the JSON data like this:

```js
var getResult = (jsonData['participants'] as List).map(
  (e) => Name1Name2.fromJson(e),
).toList();
```

Comment: it is giving this error now :
**NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("Name1Name2"))**

Comment: Can you print the value of jsonData before this line? Just to make sure it is being decoded correctly and it is not null.

Comment: Yeap, the print result is this -
**jsonData: {JohnJakiro: [{senderName: John, message: jhgcv}]}**

"John & Jakiro" are the names of the users ( sender + receiver, John is Sender, Jakiro is receiver. hence the name Name1Name2 in JSON file )

Comment: The error is trying to read the data using `Name1Name2` as the key. As you can see you are receiving the data with the `JohnJakiro` key. It does not magically know that `JohnJakiro` is `Name1Name2`. You need to specify the key exaclty as you receive it.

Comment: in JSON file it gets updated to correct (Sender + Receiver) when i send a message

Comment: You need to know who both is Sender+Receiver in order to decode the JSON data. You need to specify a fixed key for decoding. It is basic JSON data handling. If you want to receive the Sender and Receiver data use another JSON architecture.

Comment: I edited my answer with a new JSON model you can use and will give you the data you need.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try it and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn [null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety) but let me tell you how to fix your current code. It is simple!

Put a question mark `?` before calling `.map()`. You should do that **everywhere**. For example, this should be

```dart
jsonData["Name1Name2"].map( ......
```

like this

```dart
jsonData["Name1Name2"]?.map( ......
```

The question mark `?` simply check if the value before it is `null` and return `null` if it is or process the rest if it isn't.

Comment: You can fix it like this but the main purpose is not achieved, which is decoding the JSON data. I mean, doing this avoid the program to fail but it will never map the Name1Name2 data which in fact exists.

Comment: @MyoWin
thank you for the help, but it is again throwing error 
***Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<MessageModel>>')*

Comment: @AbelRodríguez This is what she needed because of the error message she provided. I have read the whole question and that's why I am giving this answer.

Comment: @SrastiVerma that is because you are expecting `Future<List<MessageModel>>` from `getMessages()` function. 

You need to make sure you are getting the actual data from the API response. What do you get if you do `print(getResponse.body);` ?

Comment: After reading your replies under @AbelRodríguez answer, I realized that `["Name1Name2"]` is dynamic. You must know the key of the object you are accessing. Dynamic value is bad and yes, you should restructure your API response.

Comment: after printing `getResponse.body` , i get

`{
   "JohnJakiro": [
     {
       "senderName": "John",
       "message": "hey, how are you?"
     }
   ]
 }`

Comment: If you are restructuring your api response, make sure to return sender and receiver as `id`s instead of `name`s because you will need their id, name and avatar to build the UI. With their ids you can get those informations in separate network requests.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
if (getResponse.statusCode == 200) {
 
  String getData = getResponse.body;

  var jsonData =
      await json.decode(getData);

  var getResult = jsonData["Name1Name2"].map(
    (e) => Name1Name2.fromJson(e),
  );




  return getResult; 
} else {
  return [];
}
```

dont forget to import 'dart:convert';

Answer (score 0):

[image: https://app.quicktype.io/]

1. As you are looking/decoding the json is not right, so the following website will help you do it - [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/). I highly encourage you to explore the website with different options.
2. As [@Mayo Win](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2218290/myo-win) said. You do need to learn **Null Safety** feature. Otherwise it make your code prone to error.
3. From your method `getMessages()` just call the following -

```
CustomDataModel customDataModel = customDataModelFromJson(response.bodyString ?? '');
```